# Arduino, Visual C# best Serial comunication

Tags: c#, c, arduino, serial-port, port

I'm new to Arduino and serial ports and I want to make the best communication between Arduino and my C# program. In my code I want to control one or more servo motors fast as possible. This is my Arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo serv;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(5);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  serv.attach(9);
}

String msg;
void loop() {
  String val = Serial.readString();
  if(val!=0) {
    if(val.startsWith("U")) {
      val.replace("U","");
      serv.write(val.toInt());
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  if(Serial.available()>0) {
    msg = "U";
    msg = msg+serv.read();
    Serial.println(msg);
  }
}
```

And my C# program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace arduino_servo {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    SerialPort port;
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      init();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    private void init() {
      port = new SerialPort();
      port.PortName = "COM5";
      port.BaudRate = 115200;
      port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Primire_date);
      try {
        port.Open();
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Eroare",ex.Message,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (port.IsOpen) {
        port.WriteLine("U"+trackBar1.Value.ToString());
      }
    }

    private void Primire_date(object emitator, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
      string msg = port.ReadLine();
      if (msg.IndexOf("U") > -1) {
        msg = msg.Replace("U", "");
        label1.Text = msg;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you guys could give me some advice or some modifications, I would be very thankful. My communication is a bit laggy.

Comment: the question is about `C#` not `C`,  please remove the `C` tag

Comment: I wouldn't create val over and over again like you're doing. Declare and initialize it in setup() and use it in loop(). I don't think this is causing your performance issue but it's still a bit strange to keep declaring it each time around the loop.

Comment: It also seems you would want to set val = Serial.readString() only if there's serial data available. At no point is Val=0 unless readString() returns that if the buffer is empty. Look that behavior up. It probably doesn't return 0, so it's running that first if block in loop() every time around, even when there's nothing worthwhile to do. Start by really looking at what your loop actually does and re-writing it so that it does what you think it does. Maybe ditch the serial.println() report back to the pc to see if that is hurting performance as well.

Comment: @user3629249 arduino code is in C

Comment: @GC78 i will change this. thanks

Comment: @GC78 yeah. but i want to send and recieve information in the same time. i  don't think this is performance issue because you have 2 different pins TX and RX and i think it's works independently.

Comment: I'm saying the serial.printline() function in the arduino library may not be very efficient. These arduino libraries are not really made for speed. They are made so that artists and hobbyists can write code without really having to know how to write code. Who knows what that serial.printline() function really does when compiled to the particular model arduino board you have. How many instructions does it end up doing for each byte that it sends? It's quick to remove the call to see if it speeds it up.